# How to delete only the top record from a table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-delete

I'm just looking for simple code which deletes the top record from a table.

I've tried:

```
SqlCommand Delete = new SqlCommand("Command String", cn);
cn.Open();
Delete.CommandText = "DELETE TOP (1) queue.* FROM queue  ";
Delete.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close();
```

But I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '*'.

`TOP` only seems to work with `SELECT`.

Comment: Try this one.  `DELETE TOP 1  FROM queue`

Comment: yes alway the top record that needs to removed. only problem now is getting the datagrid to refresh after deleteing the record

Comment: @ghost10000 - You are missing the point. You may always want to delete the first row, but SQL won't guarantee it will return you the first row every time.DELETE TOP(1) doesn't delete the first row. It deletes the first row that SQL decides to return you. Look here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175486%28v=sql.105%29.aspx. Then see my answer below

Comment: Per SQL standard rows are ordered __if and only if__ you order them by a `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
DELETE TOP(1) FROM queue
```

However, this will just delete a random row (most likely the first row, but not necessarily). You probably want to do something more meaningful, such as this:

```
DELETE FROM queue WHERE queueId IN (
     SELECT TOP 1 queueId FROM queue ORDER BY queueId
)
```

This is just an example. I don't know your table structure or fields, so you'll need to decide how to order it yourself. Keep in mind that issuing "DELETE TOP (1) from queue" will not necessarily delete the first row. What it does is it deletes the first row SQL server decided to serve you. It may or may not be the first row in your table though.

Comment: i had to add another column with an Identity Increment to ensure first record in first record out but it works. thank you for your help :)

Comment: This is how I would write the second example _without using TOP_ : `DELETE FROM queue WHERE queueId  = (SELECT MIN(queueId) FROM queue)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your sql query for deleting the top record is wrong.

Replace This:

```
Delete.CommandText = "DELETE TOP (1) queue.* FROM queue  ";
```

With

```
Delete.CommandText = "DELETE TOP(1) FROM queue";
```

Comment: I echo @icemanind's comment. This deletes an _arbitrary_ row. There is no such thing as a 'top' row without an order by. If you just want to delete one random row at a time this is OK. Remember it's random!